# baseurl64 buffer decoding

Tags: node.js, encoding, buffer, base64url

Can someone explain this behavior?

```js
Buffer.from('5d9RAjZ2GCob-86_Ql', 'base64url').toString('base64url')

// 5d9RAjZ2GCob-86_Qg
```

Please take a close look at the last character `l - g`

Comment: Base 64 encodes chunks of 3 bytes (for this reasons it has often either a protocol which decide the length, or the = at the end of a base64 string). I assume `l` and `g` will give the same bits for the last entire byte, and the rest is discarded because there is not enough information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is 18 characters long, With 6 bits encoded in each character it means the first 16 characters represent 96 bits (12 bytes) and the last two represent one byte plus 4 unused bits. Only the first two bits of the last character are significant here. `g` is 100000, `l` is 100101. As the last 4 characters are not used, `g` is just the first choice for the two bits 1 0.

So for any character in the range between `g` and `v`, you would get a `g` when you convert it back to Base64Url.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table_from_RFC_4648